# Prove that there exists a subsequence $\{g_{n_k}(x)\}$ converging uniformly to a continuous function $g(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

Let $f\in L^1[0,1]$, $E_n\subset[0,1]$ be measurable subsets and
$$g_n(x)=\int_0^x\chi_{E_n}(t)f(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
where $\chi_{E_n}$ is the characteristic function of the set $E_n$.
Prove that there exists a subsequence $\{g_{n_k}(x)\}$ converging uniformly to a continuous function $g(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

I tried to prove that $\{g_n\}$ is equicontinuous but I can only do it when $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Equicontinuity follows from Holder’s inequality where you estimate $f$ in $L^1$ and $\chi_{E_n}$ in $L^\infty$ in the domain $[x,y]$ where $0\le x < y \le 1.$

Comment: thank you. @User8128

Comment: Using this method, I show that $|g_n(x)-g_n(y)|\le\int_x^y|f(t)|\mathrm{d}t$. But how to prove that this is small? @User8128

Comment: Since $f$ is $L^1$ we have that $\int_x^y |f(t)|dt \leq (y-x)||f||_{L^1}$. That should give you everything.

Comment: Thanks very much. @LeeFisher